# Any command to change the visual studio project configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have so many projects(c#) in my visual studio solution. I want to create a script file which can change the configuration of the project to debug/release. Is there any command to do this from command prompt?

Thanks in advance

Varun

Comment: Tried anything so far? Checked where is the debug or release build determined? Tried to change the value in that file?

Comment: @Kamil T I think OP doesn't know the way itself.  So he needs a way.  Better provide an option where to set it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a such setting.
Alternative way to batch build multiple solutions in command line, list all solution files into a list through command and iterate each solution name, and use msbuild command with the right configuration you want.